# How to get Modulus and Exponent from RSA private key in iOS Swift?

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key

How to parse RSA private key in order to get modulus(n) and exponent(e) from it?

**RSA Private Key Example** --->

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful here.

Comment: I think, you should add the syntax of the key(even if it is a self-answer) or provide an example key(not a production key!)

Comment: @dan1st thank you, i have updated the answer as suggested.

Comment: I think that should be in the question.

Comment: @dan1st my bad, done as suggested.

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz thank you , surely i'll go through that and will follow in future.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
func parsePrivateSecKey(privateKey: SecKey) -> (mod: Data, exp: Data) {
        let pubAttributes = SecKeyCopyAttributes(privateKey) as! [String: Any]
        
        print("pubAttributes----\(pubAttributes)")
        
        // let keydata = pubAttributes[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String] as! [String: Any]
        // print("----key data ------===\(keydata)")
        
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: "")
        // Check that this is really an RSA key
        guard Int(pubAttributes[kSecAttrKeyType as String] as! String) ==
                Int(kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA as String)
        else {
                // throw "Tried to parse non-RSA key as RSA key"
                return (mod: data!, exp: data!)
        }
        
        // Check that this is really a private key
        guard    Int(pubAttributes[kSecAttrKeyClass as String] as! String)
            == Int(kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate as String)
            else {
                // throw "Tried to parse non-private key as private key"
                return (mod: data!, exp: data!)
        }
        
        let keySize = pubAttributes[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String] as! Int
        
        // Extract values
        let pubData  = pubAttributes[kSecValueData as String] as! Data
        print("pubData---\(pubData)")
        //  SecKeyCopyModulus
        
        //Find modulus data length
        let modulusLengthData = pubData.subdata(in: 9..<11)
        print(modulusLengthData as NSData)
        let modulusLength = BigUInt(modulusLengthData)
        print("mod lenth ===\(modulusLength)")
        //find MODULUS
        var modulus  = pubData.subdata(in: 11..<(Int(modulusLength) + 11))
        let reqMod = BigUInt(modulus)
        print("final modulus====\(reqMod)")
        
        //Find exponent data length
        var expDataLength = pubData.subdata(in: (Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7)..<(Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 1))
        print(expDataLength as NSData)
        var bytes_to_find : [UInt8] = [0xFF]    //0xFF = 255 size
        let datafind = Data(bytes: &bytes_to_find, count: bytes_to_find.count)
        let range = expDataLength.range(of: datafind, options: [], in: Range(NSRange(location: 0, length: expDataLength.count)))
        var exponentLength = BigUInt(expDataLength)
        print("exponent lenth ===\(exponentLength)")
        //Find EXPONENT
        var exponent  = pubData.subdata(in: (Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 1)..<(Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 1 + Int(exponentLength)))
        //check if its size is 255 or more and get data length accordingly
        if range == nil {
            expDataLength = pubData.subdata(in: (Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7)..<(Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 2))
            print("0xFF not found...")
            exponentLength = BigUInt(expDataLength)
            print("exponent lenth ===\(exponentLength)")
            //Find EXPONENT
            exponent  = pubData.subdata(in: (Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 1)..<(Int(modulusLength) + 11 + 7 + 2 + Int(exponentLength)))

        }
        
        
        let reqExp = BigUInt(exponent)
        print("final exponent====\(reqExp)")
        
        if modulus.count > keySize / 8 { // --> 257 bytes
            modulus.removeFirst(1)
        }
        
        return (mod: modulus, exp: exponent)
    }
```

Comment: Does this work?  What libary are you using for BigUInt?

Comment: @Herbal7ea apologies for late reply, and yes **it works** and using **BigInt** library for BigUInt